# AMD/NVIDIA GPU driver configuration

Tags: gpu, gpu-driver

This is a bit of a [cross-post for Folding@Home](https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=31787&p=308445#p308445). I want to verify I have everything as far as Ubuntu goes configured correctly. My GPUs are as follows:

- GeForce 980 ti
- GeForce 1070
- Vega 56

Ubuntu is 18.04 x64, latest updates, headless, no GUI/desktop packages. Both my NVIDIA cards work fine, Folding@Home is able to use them. I configured them using the following packages:

- nvidia-driver-390
- ocl-icd-opencl-dev

The OpenCL package is multi-vendor, so I thought it'd work for my Vega. I followed this (says Frontier but I grabbed the [Ubuntu x86 64-bit section](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-56)), basically installing straight from AMD: https://gpuopen.com/vega-frontier-installing-the-driver. No joy. I then tried installing *mesa-opencl-icd*, but that caused all my GPUs to stop folding, so I uninstalled it.

`clinfo` doesn't list my Vega.

`lspci` shows `05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64] (rev c3)`

*05:00.0* is bound to */sys/bus/pci/drivers/amdgpu*.

Folding related logs, are these two entries:

```
ERROR:No compute devices matched GPU #2 AMD:5 [Radeon Rx vega].  You may need to update your graphics drivers.
ERROR:WU03:FS03:Failed to start core: OpenCL device matching slot 3 not found, try setting 'opencl-index' manually.
```

(Setting the `opencl-index` to either 0 or 1 will result in a faulty work unit, so same result. The fact that the client cannot locate all OpenCL devices itself is a problem.)

Update:

I took a look at the [AMD instructions](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html#installing-the-all-open-variant). I realized there was a headless mode, and the silent install doesn't install OpenCL (specifically mentioning headless compute setups).

- Ran `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and `apt-get autoremove`
- Rebooted
- Ran `./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy --headless`
- Rebooted

Causes all slots to fail again.